# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `price_cents`): error after rails upgrading to rail 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have upgraded my rails app which was earlier on rails 4.1 to rails 5.1.
Now I am getting an error while using `acts_as_shopping_cart` gem, which is on version `0.4.1`

I tried many things but not sure why exactly I am getting this error, while adding item to cart

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute price_cents):
```

`app/models/shopping_cart.rb:11:in add`
`app/controllers/shopping_carts_controller.rb:38:in add_to_cart`

Any suggestions on this, will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this one is still not yet supported for Rails 5 `https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart`, you could try this one `https://github.com/dabit/acts_as_shopping_cart`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, already tried this. But same issue

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but I was banging my head on this one for too long so I thought this may help other people.

You're getting the MissingAttributeError because your shopping_carts table doesn't have a price_cents field. The previous version of acts_as_shopping_cart (~ 0.2.2) was setup to use a float field called price, and it did not use the money-rails gem.  The newer versions (>= 0.4.0) use money-rails and an integer field called price_cents, then money-rails "automagically" creates a attribute called "price" that converts to/from the price_cents field.

You may be able to migrate your price field using one of their helpers:
https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#migration-helpers